# Reference Listview with mutliple columns in email portion using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, email, listview

So a follow up question to my other one, I figured out how to email and send text via email from the form but I am having some trouble referencing the listview data in the body of the email portion.

The result comes out as this:"Lis Lis" in the email.

Even when I have 3 columns and two rows of data in my list view. I am not sure how to reference the list view, anyone have any idea? The code is listed below.

```
Private Sub LoadPDF_Data()
    sqlCon = New SqlConnection(stlCon)

    Using (sqlCon)

        Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand


        sqlComm.Connection = sqlCon


        sqlComm.CommandText = "sp_GetDocs"
        sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOCID", Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text.Trim()))

        sqlCon.Open()
        Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()

        Using sqlReader
            Dim table As New DataTable
            table.Load(sqlReader)

            ListView1.View = View.Details
            ListView1.GridLines = True
            ListView1.Columns.Add("PDF Name", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
            ListView1.Columns.Add("PDF Description", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
            ListView1.Columns.Add("PDF Location", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

            For Each row In table.Rows

                Dim PDF As New ListViewItem
                PDF.Text = row.Item(0)
                PDF.SubItems.Add(row.item(1))
                PDF.SubItems.Add(row.item(2))

                For i = 1 To table.Columns.Count - 1
                    PDF.SubItems.Add(row(i).ToString(0))
                    PDF.SubItems.Add(row(i).ToString(1))
                    PDF.SubItems.Add(row(i).ToString(2))

                Next
                ListView1.Items.Add(PDF)
            Next
            ListView1.EndUpdate()

        End Using

    End Using

End Sub
Private Function BuildTheListViewItemsToSend(ByVal path As ListView)

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        For i = 1 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
            sb.Append((ListView1.Items(i).ToString(0)) & (ListView1.Items(i).ToString(1)) & (ListView1.Items(i).ToString(2)) & vbCrLf)
        Next

    Next

    Return sb.ToString()

End Function
Private Sub EmailInfo()
    Dim MailFrom As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress
    Dim MailTo As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress
    Dim MailSubject As String
    Dim MailBody As String
    Dim Mail As New MailMessage
    Dim MailClient As SmtpClient
    Dim List As String = BuildTheListViewItemsToSend(ListView1)

    Try
        MailBody = (BuildTheListViewItemsToSend(ListView1))

        MailSubject = ("Documents for the DOCID: " + TextBox1.Text)
        MailFrom = New MailAddress(TextBox2.Text)
        MailTo = New MailAddress(TextBox3.Text)

        Mail.From = MailFrom
        Mail.To.Add(MailTo)
        Mail.Subject = MailSubject
        Mail.Body = MailBody



        MailClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com")
        MailClient.Port = 587
        MailClient.EnableSsl = True
        MailClient.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox2.Text, "password", "domain")

        MailClient.Send(Mail)
        MsgBox("Email Sent")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    LoadPDF_Data()
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Email_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Email.Click
    EmailInfo()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem code, correct?

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
    For i = 1 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        sb.Append((ListView1.Items(i).ToString(0)) & (ListView1.Items(i).ToString(1)) & (ListView1.Items(i).ToString(2)) & vbCrLf)
    Next

Next
```

Inside your `For Each` loop of the list view items, you are looping through the same collection a second time, and trying to access the columns through `.ToString(0)`. You needed to move a level deeper into the SubItems (columns) of each ListViewItem (each row).

The following uses `For Each` so you don't have to mess around with indexes. It accesses all of the subitems and then finally appends the new line before moving onto the next row.

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items 
    For Each subitem As ListViewSubItem In item.SubItems
        sb.Append(subitem.Text)
    Next
    sb.Append(vbCrLf)
Next
```

Comment: thank you so much it works! Last question the results are all in one line in the email if I want to format it to a table like how it looks in the form would I format it in the email portion or the BuildTheListViewItemsToSend portion? can I use the same formatting used in the beginning? I apologize for asking alot of questions I am still new to vb.net

Comment: Hmmm.. Because the columns are text which can have huge variations in length, it will be difficult to format without actually having a table available. The easiest solution would be to have it formatted in blocks (Which I can't format properly in a comment haha)

Comment: haha I see thank you for all the help this helped with the biggest obstacle of getting the data in the email, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're looping through the ListView items twice in your Function.  This code will turn your ListView contents into a string:

```
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        For Each column As ListViewSubItem In item.SubItems
            sb.Append(column.Text)
        Next
        sb.Append(vbCrLf)
    Next
```

Hopefully you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: thank you for replying! i tweaked it to subitems like how Programmer stated below and it works only issue left is formatting the email and I am not sure where that would go like in the email portion or the BuildListview portion

Comment: Hi, you'd have to do it in the BuildTheListViewItemsToSend method.  What you do would depend on how you want the mail to look.  Are you planning to send an email in HTML format which would give you more flexibility over how it looks or a simple text mail.  If you just change the line to `sb.Append(column.Text + vbTab)` it will look better in the email but won't always be perfect